# How to use my own output for Action methods

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, actionmethod

How can I use my own output type for action methods in MVC?
I know that its possible (as they did in MVC Contrib), but how?!
I'm trying to use Silverlight as MVC Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll still need to host the silverlight object tag / XAP in some html, won't you?

Comment: No. I wanna use MVC Input and outputs in order to use a complete silverlight project as view and just use MVC as server side responder...

Comment: Its better I ask my question in another way.
I wanna use MVC as my model and server side responder and maybe use some services or ST like that in middle and use silverlight as view in client side.
but the idea is that, I said it should be possible to make some class libraries and add it to MVC engine in order to do this faster...
thanks for your helps...